# Magento 2: How to allow updating a null value for a column having foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, magento, foreign-keys, magento2

I have 2 tables A and B

### A

- id
- name

### B

- id
- name
- a_id FK references A(id)

I used the Magento's upgrade script to add both tables, everything was created correctly, however when i tried to setting a_id to null via Magento code it throws a FK exception:

```
Something went wrong while saving the B.SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

However when i tried updating the column via MySQL directly i have no problems:

```
UPDATE B SET a_id = null WHERE id = 1;
```

So it is Magento's `Magento\Framework\ForeignKey\Strategy\Restrict` that is not allowing this operation. How can i avoid this restriction then since MySQL didn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, the reason was that before being passed to the table, the NULL value was recalced and turned into Int = 0.